# Why is this usage of "<-" resulting in a correct computation of a powerset?

Tags: haskell, monads

So my book gives the following code for the calculation of a powerset:

```
filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM p [] = return []
filterM p (x:xs) = do b <- p x
                      ys <- filterM p xs
                      return (if b then x:ys else ys)

filterM (\x -> [True,False]) [1,2,3]
```

> result: `[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]`

I just don't se as to how the result of `p` (being `[True,False]`) is usable in `return (if b then x:ys else ys)`

Intuitively I'm guessing that this `filterM` applies the list `b` in such a way that every possible permutation is returned. That being `x:ys` and `ys`. But I'm just not seeing where it is happening.

---

Seems like I'm misunderstanding `<-` as assignment. It gets translated into a call to (>>=) (bind). But I don't get how this will result in multiple instantions of `b`.

Comment: `do { b <- p x ; ys <- filterM p xs ; return (if b then x:ys else ys) }` is equivalent to `[ (if b then x:ys else ys) | b <- p x , ys <- filterM p xs ]` is equivalent to `concat [ [ if b then x:ys else ys | ys <- filterM p xs] | b <- p x ]`, or in pseudocode: `for b in p x: for ys in filterM p xs : yield (if b then x:ys else ys)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mistake is interpreting `<-` as a straight assignment. This is wrong. `b <- p x` is handled by the `>>=` operator where:

> [Essentially, each `<-` is generating a set of values which is passed on into the remainder of the monadic computation.](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html)

As such instead of `b` being `[True,False]` it is instatiated with `True` and `False` in each iteration of the remainder of the computation. Resulting in valid `if True then x:ys else ys` and `if False then x:ys else ys`.

Comment: Indeed. The purpose of the list monad is to model nondeterminism. You can think of the `do` construct as "forking" into multiple parallel combinations, where `b` has a different value from `p x` in each branch. The results of each branch are implicitly joined back into a single list.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have answered your own question, but I think it might be interesting to add some information on the implementation of other parts of the `do`-notation.
So:

1. `x <- m; e` is `m >>= \x -> e`;
2. `e; e'` (`;` is newline) is `e >> e'`;
3. `let x = ...; e` is what it is: `let x = ... in do e`;

Therefore the recursive branch of your program actually looks like this:

```
filterM p (x:xs) = p x >>= \b ->
                   filterM p xs >>= \ys ->
                   return (if b then x:ys else ys)
```

Even though I made my answer look like a complete list, it is certainly not. For example, if you enable `RecursiveDo`, you would get a new layer of syntactic sugar: the well-known `mfix` function underlies the `rec` keyword and the `mdo`-notation. I am sure there are other examples which did not spring to my mind right off the bat.